# Can I use weak references as instance variables in Windows RT/8?

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-8, microsoft-metro, c++-cx

I'm implementing a tree in one of my projects. Each node contains a vector with zero or more child nodes in it. Each node also contains a reference to its parent (the root's parent reference being nullptr). Here's an example of the class definition:

```
ref class TreeNode {
    ...

    TreeNode^ _parentNode;
    Platform::Collections::Vector<TreeNode^>^ _childNodes;
}
```

First, will this cause a memory leak? I'm assuming these are strong references in both directions and thus the ref counts on the objects will remain above zero.

I've seen examples of Platform::WeakReference, but never as instance variables. Is this possible? What would the syntax look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your code as written will result in a reference-counting cycle and your tree will leak.

`Platform::WeakReference` can be an instance variable, but as it is a C++-only type it cannot be on the public surface of `TreeNode`.  Whenever you want to access the weak reference you should call `.Resolve<TreeNode>()` on the weak reference to create a strong reference.  You might consider using a property for the weak reference:

```
ref class TreeNode sealed {
public:
    property TreeNode^ Parent {
        TreeNode^ get(){
            return _parentNode.Resolve<TreeNode>();
        }

        void set(TreeNode^ tn) {
            _parentNode = tn;
        }
    };

private:
    Platform::WeakReference _parentNode;
    Platform::Collections::Vector<TreeNode^>^ _childNodes;
};
```

Comment: Spot on! Thanks for the example.

Comment: Oh, one quick correction on your code. When resolving a WeakReference, you don't specify the ^ in the template. The fifth line should read `return _parentNode.Resolve<TreeNode>();`

Comment: Ah - good point.  I've updated the code example to remove those hats.  That's what I get for writing code without trying to compile it... :)

Comment: I've since learned that Platform::WeakReference also overrides the = (equals) operator. Instead of setting `_parentNode = Platform::WeakReference(tn);`, you can just write `_parentNode = tn;`.